# How to connect to GUI of a virtual machine that was started with vmwares vmrun CLI command?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmrun

I am managing virtual machines with VMWare Workstation pro 16 on a Ubuntu server. And to avoid always having to RDP into the machine, I am using vmwares cli command `vmrun` to start/stop the virtual machines. One of the virtual machines is having what seems to be some network issues and I am trying to get on the machine. Since I can't ssh into it, I need to connect to it directly through the host machine.

Now here is my question. With the vmrun command starting the vm from cli, there is no UI for the vm when I RDP onto the server which they are hosted. Can I somehow bring the UI up from the already running VM and connect to that? It is possible for me to bring down the machine with `vmrun stop` then restart the machine in the UI, but this is an undesired approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PowerCLI this website could help you https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2013/10/opening-the-virtual-machine-remote-console-through-powercli.html